# Android file system: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /savedArticlesFile: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Tags: java, android, io, filenotfoundexception

I keep getting said error even after reading every Stack Overflow question on it I can find and trying several different methods of creating the file. I currently have the following two methods for reading and writing a set of Objects to internal storage:

```
public HashSet<PrestoItem> readSavedArticleFile() {
    Log.d("snw", "readSavedArticlesFile()");
    String filename = "savedArticlesFile";
    String filePath = getActivity().getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/" + filename;
    File savedArticlesFile = new File(filePath);
    ObjectInputStream input;
    HashSet<PrestoItem> articleSet = null;

    // retrieve article set
    try {
        input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(savedArticlesFile));
        articleSet = (HashSet<PrestoItem>) input.readObject();
        input.close();
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (articleSet == null) {
        articleSet = new HashSet<PrestoItem>();
    }

    return articleSet;
}

public void saveArticleSet(HashSet<PrestoItem> articleSet) {
    // write set back to file
    String filename = "savedArticlesFile";
    String filePath = getActivity().getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/" + filename;
    ObjectOutput output;
    try {
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        output.writeObject(articleSet);
        output.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Whenever I hit a try block, i.e. attempt to open an input or output stream, I get the ROFS error. I was under the impression the path I supplied should have both r/w permissions enabled, but it throws the error even on reads. I'm obviously misunderstanding something, somewhere. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Stack Trace

```
11-05 15:40:09.659  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner/files/savedArticlesFile: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-05 15:40:09.659  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
11-05 15:40:09.659  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at com.gannett.dolly_android.WebAppLoaderFragment.readSavedArticleFile(WebAppLoaderFragment.java:378)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at com.gannett.dolly_android.WebAppLoaderFragment$2.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebAppLoaderFragment.java:225)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:293)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(AwContentsClientBridge.java:96)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
11-05 15:40:09.669  26726-26726/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner W/System.err﹕ ... 15 more
```

Comment: Based on the error message it looks like *someplace else* you might be trying to use the filename on its own without the path prefix.  Please edit the actual stack trace of the error into your question, and then include the referenced code if it is not what you already posted.  Also clean and rebuild and deploy your project to make sure the version you are running matches your latest source code.

Comment: Try with getActivity().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + your file name. I think the dir with the name 'files' does not yet exist. Use file.exists() to check and create if needed with mkdirs().

Comment: @ChrisStratton Please see my edited question, I have pasted in the stack trace

Comment: @greenapps You might be on to something, I thought if the file didn't exist Android just created it automatically. Could you go into a bit more detail on the code to create the file using mkdirs()?

Comment: No not to create the file but to create the directory first.

Comment: `/data/data/com.gannett.dolly.CooksCorner/files/savedArticlesFile`. So what i said was that the 'files' sub directory probably does not yet exist. Adapt your save to file code to begin with.

Comment: @greenapps I thought the directory should exist as well, since I'm directly asking the system for it. What would the code to create the directory look like? Something like

if (!savedArticleFile.exists()) {
    savedArticleFile.mkdirs();
}

or is that way off?

Comment: Yes. That is the way to do it. But do create it only during save() before you create the file. And check existence during read().

Comment: Sorry. It is ofcourse NOT savedArticleFile that you have to use for .exists() and mkdirs() but getFilesDir(). You have to check if the directory exists (not the file) and make it if not. Then when the directory exists you can create a file in it.

Comment: I think you are in trouble now if you already tried with savedArticleFile as you will have created a directory with the intended file name. If so then delete it first. You have to.

Comment: No, the "files" directory already exists.  The problem here (and it is a **different problem than the original report**) is that you are trying to open a **file** which you have not yet created.  Creating a File object does not create a file on disk; but creating an FileOutputStream does.  **Likely you are simply trying to read before you have written.**

Comment: But Chris i see nothing wrong in his `saveArticleSet()`. (Well except for a missing dir).

Comment: You were both right, I wound up implementing what both of you were saying and it's now functioning properly. Thanks so much for getting me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `directory.mkdirs()` instead of `directory.mkdir()`